# Is there a correct way to spot non-fatal errors in js?

Tags: javascript, debugging, d3.js, chromium

I'm new to debugging the js. This is my first week playing with js and I'm learning it through D3.js. I have a few years' recreational experience with python.

I have here passed a value `d` to anon functions. Imagine for example that `d == [55, 601]`.

```
circles.attr({
    cx: function(d) { return xScale(d[0]) },
    cy: function(d) { return yScale(d[1]) },
    r: function(d) { return rScale( d[1] ) },
    fill: function(d) { return colorScale(d) }  <<<< Attention here.
    });
```

Javascript did not return any error. The circles were rendered with the correct `cx` and `cy` and `r` values but with `fill="#NaNNaNNaN"`. However the chrome debug tool gave me:

```
> colorScale(500)
< "#7d0082"
```

When I do this in python I get:

```
TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 2
```

Back to js, after 1.5 hours debugging I discovered that passing `parseInt(d)` to the function works. But that's not the answer. This is the answer:

```
    fill: function(d) { return colorScale(d[0]) }  <<<< Fixed.
```

**My questions:**

- The code ran and did not give me an error. Does this behavior come from javascript, D3 or chromium web tools?
- Does this kind of mistake raise an error message anywhere?

Comment: Welcome to JavaScript! The error is quite typical. JavaScript functions, regardless of their declaration, can be called with any number of parameters.

Comment: @Pointy Not to mention of any type. Though JS will usually dutifully attempt to coerce the passed argument to the necessary type. (depending on what's happening in the function)

Comment: Also, because parameters don't have a type (though values do) you can't specify that *d* must be an array, so the debugger can't tell that an array is expected so can't throw when one isn't passed. But **you** can check if you want (e.g. using [*Array.isArray*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.isarray)). But type checking is wearisome, so most program around it (e.g. pass separate primitive values, not an array of values).

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! So far so good except for this hiccup here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The code ran and did not give me an error. Does this behavior come from javascript, D3 or chromium web tools?

It's javascript (actually ECMAScript, which is the underlying programming language).

> Does this kind of mistake raise an error message anywhere?

It depends. For example, if the function expects an array but gets a primitive and tries to use an array method, you'll get an error for that, e.g.

```js
// @param {Array} arr
// @returns arr
function foo(arr) {
  arr.push('bar');
  return arr;
}

// Call with an array
document.write(foo([]))  // bar 

// Call with a primitive instead
document.write('<br>' + foo(6))  // In console: Uncaught TypeError: arr.push is not a function
```

But if you just try to access a named property, no. Since ECMAScript helpfully coerces values to a type appropriate for the operation, then in:

```
var x = 3;
alert(x.length); // undefined
```

the primitive value is coerced to an object momentarily to get its *length* property. Since it doesn't have one, *undefined* is returned. Try:

```
alert(x.toString); // function() { [native code] }
```

which "works" because Numbers have a *toString* method inherited from *Number.prototype*.

Comment: Thanks @RobG this is very helpful.